# How do I put a progress bar in a messagebox in tkinter in python?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to put a progress bar in a message box to display the progress of downloading of files; something like this:

[image: example]

(Image taken from [here](http://uucode.com/texts/pylongopgui/pyguiapp.html).)

So for the progress bar I will use this :

```
pbar=ttk.Progressbar(app,orient='horizontal',length=200,mode='determinate')
pbar.pack()
```

And maybe I could use a text widget, but I am not so sure how to make this new window appear. Do I write something like this?

```
root1=Tk()
root1.title("Status Dialog")
pbar=ttk.Progressbar(app,orient='horizontal',length=200,mode='determinate')
pbar.pack()

root1.mainloop()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The page, where you found the image, contains the source code. Just look into it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an error: in your code, `pbar=ttk.ProgressBar(app, ...)` should be replaced by `pbar=ttk.ProgressBar(root1, ...)`. In this class instantiation, the first argument is the parent widget, and I bet it should be `root1` in your code.

But as written by brc in comment, we can't be sure as long as you do not describe your error (give us the Traceback for example).